# What is the lifecycle of S3Client

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

In my server communication code on the client side, I create an instance of an `S3Client` like this:

```
S3Client s32 = S3Client.builder()
            //.credentialsProvider()
            .region(Region.US_WEST_1)
            .build();
```

Can I make `s32` a member variable of a class so that the `S3Client` instance is alive as long as the application is running or should I create a new instance of `S3Client` every time I have to communicate with S3?

I'll probably pull 5 files from S3 on average every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the client around and use it whenever and as often as you wish.

Comment: So this object doesn't go online right? It just uses the credentials and the region to create an object that can go online when an appropriate method is called on it like `putObject()`

Comment: I _think_ that is correct, but I haven't tried it with java. I have tested it with Python using boto3 by disconnecting my computer from the network and then creating an S3 client object. Worked fine. You can try the same with Java, let us know what you discover!